# Angular 6: pass viewContainerRef from template

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 6 app; a component method needs access to the `viewContainerRef` of any given element in the component's template in order to pass it to a service method.  Here is what I'm currently doing.  It works but I'm hoping for simpler:

```
<div #myDiv></div>
<button (click)="doWork()"></button>
```

And in the component:

```
@ViewChild('myDiv', {read: ViewContainerRef}) divView: ViewContainerRef;

doWork() {
  this.service.work(this.divView);
}
```

So `doWork` needs the `viewContainer`.  What I'm hoping for is more straightforward, like this:

```
<div #myDiv></div>
<button (click)="doWork(???)"></button>
```

Is there some way I can pass in the viewContainer directly from the template into `doWork`?

Comment: Yes  you can pass the template ref

Comment: @Chellappan I need the `ViewContainerRef`, not the template ref.  Please share code if you have a solution.

Comment: You could pass `divView` as an argument to `doWork` inside of the template, but I guess that you want to get rid of `@ViewChild` altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in approach. You could however create a directive that makes the ViewContainerRef available in the template:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[viewContainer]',
  exportAs: 'viewContainer'
})
export class ViewContainerDirective {
  constructor(public container: ViewContainerRef) {
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oydor5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You you can access the variable anywhere inside the template. For example:

```
<div #myDiv></div>
<button (click)="doWork(myDiv)"></button>
```

Comment: I'm aware, but that would pass the html element to `doWork`.  I need the `ViewContainerRef`

Comment: How about `click="doWork(divView)"`? Or do you want to get rid of the @ViewChild?

Comment: @ShamPooSham right I wanted to do it without `@ViewChild` if possible.  Seems like there isn't a native way to do it.